# Open page via web if app is not installed in react native

Tags: react-native

The best example that I can think of to describe this is how VSCO does this, if you click someone's VSCO profile link, from an Instagram bio or something, you get the page via web, at the bottom of the webpage it asks you if you would rather use the app, if its installed, clicking yes will open, if its not it will link to the download page. I really don't even know where to start with the development of this so really any links and terms that I can look into are helpful.

Sorry for the somewhat open-ended question but at a loss as to where to start. If it is all using the same firebase database, could I do this all in one react native code base? Or would I want a standalone web application. Thanks ahead of time.